# Variables are getting switched up somewhere

Tags: c++, parameters

I have made a random maze generator which takes in 3 commandline arguments (Height, Width, SeedValue). The maze in itself is finished, it works most of the time, however my parameters width and height are getting switched somewhere and I cant find it. e.g. if I give the parameters 10 and 10 the width should be 10 * 5 + 1 = 51 and the Height should be 10 * 3 + 1 = 31. I now have a height of 51 and a width of 31.

Does anyone see/have any tips where these variables might get switched up?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <sstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <random>

#define North 1
#define East 2
#define South 3
#define West 4

class Maze {
    private:
        int mazeHeight;
        int mazeWidth;
        int seedValue;
        std::vector <std::vector <char>> Maze_maze;
    public:
        void checkuserInput(int Input1, int Input2);
        void mazeConstructor(int x, int y, int z, std::vector <std::vector <char>> vect);
        std::vector <std::vector <char>> initializeMaze();
};

//Make the variables accesible
void Maze::mazeConstructor(int x, int y, int z, std::vector <std::vector <char>> vect) {
    mazeWidth = x;
    mazeHeight = y;
    seedValue = z;
    Maze_maze = vect;
}
// Initialize the walls with '#'
std::vector <std::vector <char>> Maze::initializeMaze() {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Maze_maze.size(); i++) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < Maze_maze[0].size(); j++) {
            Maze_maze[i][j] = '#';
        }
    }
    return Maze_maze;
}

class Path {
    private:
        std::vector <std::vector <char>> Grid;
        int Height;
        int Width;
        int toX = 0;
        int toY = 0;
    public:
        void pathConstructor(std::vector <std::vector <char>> Maze, int mazeWidth, int mazeHeight);
        bool checkValid(int xPos, int yPos);
        void carvePath(int xPos, int yPos);
        void printMaze();
};

// Make the variables accessible
void Path::pathConstructor(std::vector <std::vector <char>> Maze, int mazeWidth, int mazeHeight) {
    Grid = Maze;
    Height = mazeHeight;
    Width = mazeWidth;
}

bool Path::checkValid(int xPos, int yPos) {
  if(xPos < 0 || xPos >= Width - 1) {
      return false;
  } 
  if( yPos < 0 || yPos >= Height) {
      return false;
  }
  return true;
} 

// Find a path using recursion
void Path::carvePath(int xPos, int yPos) {
    std::random_device dev;
    std::mt19937 rng(dev());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> randomNumber(0, 3);
    Grid[xPos][yPos] = ' ';
    std::vector <int> Directions (4);
    Directions[0] = North;
    Directions[1] = East;
    Directions[2] = South;
    Directions[3] = West;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        int toX = 0;
        int toY = 0;
        switch (Directions[randomNumber(rng)]) {
            case North: 
                toY = -1; 
                break;
            case South: 
                toY = 1; 
                break;
            case East: 
                toX = 1; 
                break;
            case West:
                toX = -1; 
                break;
        }
        int x2 = xPos + (toX << 1);
        int y2 = yPos + (toY << 1);
        if (checkValid(x2, y2)) {
            if (Grid[x2][y2] == '#') {
                Grid[x2 - toX][y2 - toY] = ' ';
                carvePath(x2, y2);
            }
        }
    }
}



// Output the maze
void Path::printMaze() {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Grid.size(); i++) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < Grid[0].size(); j++) {
            std::cout << Grid[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

// Check if user input is valid
void checkUserInput(int Input1, int Input2) {
    int checkIntWidth = 0;
    int checkIntHeight = 0;
    if (!(Input1 >> checkIntWidth) || !(Input2 >> checkIntHeight)) {
        throw std::runtime_error ("Invalid input");
    }
} 

// Get command line arguments 
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Maze c1;
    Path c2;
    srand (time(0));
    int Height;
    int Width;
    int seedValue;
    Height = atoi(argv[1]);
    Width = atoi(argv[2]);
    try {
        checkUserInput(Width, Height);
    }
    catch(std::runtime_error& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    if (argc > 3) {
        seedValue = atoi(argv[3]);
    } else {
        seedValue = rand();
    }
    std::vector <std::vector <char>> Maze (Width * 5 + 1, std::vector <char> (Height * 3 + 1));
    c1.mazeConstructor(Width, Height, seedValue, Maze);
    c2.pathConstructor(c1.initializeMaze(), Width * 5 + 1, Height * 3 + 1);
    c2.carvePath(1, 1);
    c2.printMaze();
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug the code?

Comment: You shadow the member variables `toX` and `toY` in the `carvePath` `for`-loop. That could be a problem. Avoid shadowing. It makes it very confusing.

Comment: Unrelated 1: Giving the same seed to the program does not generate the same maze. Unrelated 2: The maze doesn't fill all spaces. It may be deliberate but it looks buggy.

Comment: Note: your "input check" is equivalent to `Input1 == 0 || Input2 == 0`. It is very unclear what you intended to accomplish with the bit-shifting.

Comment: Yh the seed thing is a work in progress, I first want to have the random maze generator work. Then i'll expand

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo what does that mean, it sounds like it could help :D

Comment: @molbdnilo I want it to stream into an int, and if it cant it throws a runtime_error, it does work. I dont know if it's good code, but e.g if I input "a 10" it says invalid input

Comment: @Jojo -- Why are you introducing randomness to a program that's broken?  You should test on static, known, unchanging data first.  Once you have that working, then you introduce randomness.  Otherwise, you will be trying to debug code that's a moving target every time you run the program when attempting to pinpoint the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious thing is that you've swapped height and width in the 2d vector you create in `main`. Just correcting it, from

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> Maze(Width * 5 + 1, std::vector<char>(Height * 3 + 1));
```

to

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> Maze(Height * 3 + 1, std::vector<char>(Width * 5 + 1));
```

... will not work right out of the box though since you've multiplied `Height` and `Width` with magic numbers and you've made the same mistake in `Path` where you use `Grid[xPos][yPos]` instead of `Grid[yPos][xPos]`. Changing both corrects the problem you are asking about.

We're taught in school to think `{x, y}` but since you print row by row and that arrays in C++ is stored in [row-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order), I suggest that you use `{y, x}` everywhere in your program. That makes mistakes like this less likely.

You have some other details in the program that you could fix too.

- You copy your maze `vector` around. Pass it by reference.
- Don't create the original maze in `main`. Let the `Maze` class create (and own it).
- `Path` - if that class is even needed, should probably carve paths in the maze that is owned by `Maze`, not copy a maze from `Maze`.
- The `carvePath` algorithm sometimes "paints itself into a corner" and fails to fill the whole maze. I would probably not use recursion for this.
- Each time `carvePath` is called you create a new *pseudo random number generator*. I suggest that you only create *one* and use that for the whole program.
- The seed the user gives is not used so you'll get different mazes with the same seed.

Also, the actual vector would be simpler with a `std::string`:

```
std::vector<std::string>(Height, std::string(Width, '#'));
```

You could that just print each `std::string` in the `vector` when you want to print the maze.

```
void Path::printMaze() {
    for(auto& row : Grid) std::cout << row << '\n';
}
```

The failure to fill the whole map every time is because `Path::carvePath` only tries to find a valid direction randomly 4 times. One fix would be to increase the number of tries to a large number, making it highly unlikely that it'll fail to find all free spots, but that's a bit wasteful and will still not be 100%. A 100% fix without unnecessary tries could look like  below. Note that I've made it `{y, x}` everywhere here:

```
#include <algorithm>  // std::shuffle
#include <array>      // std::array
#include <utility>    // std::pair

// Find a path using recursion
void Path::carvePath(int yPos, int xPos) {
    static std::mt19937 rng(std::random_device{}());

    Grid[yPos][xPos] = ' ';

    // all direction pairs
    std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 4> Directions{{
        {-1, 0},
        {+1, 0},
        {0, -1},
        {0, +1},
    }};

    // ... in random order
    std::shuffle(Directions.begin(), Directions.end(), rng);

    // ... and go through all 4 - it can now not miss a free spot
    for(auto [toY, toX] : Directions) { // structured binding + range-based for loop
        int y2 = yPos + toY * 2;
        int x2 = xPos + toX * 2;
        if(checkValid(y2, x2) && Grid[y2][x2] == '#') {
            Grid[yPos + toY][xPos + toX] = ' ';
            carvePath(y2, x2);
        }
    }
}
```

If you can't use the C++17 feature [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding), you can replace that part of the loop above with:

```
    for(const auto& dir : Directions) {
        int toY = dir.first;
        int toX = dir.second;
        ...
```

Comment: So point 4 says that my I shouldn't use recursion for this, should I use a while loop instead?

Comment: @Jojo I personally wouldn't use recursion. I'd probably start by placing a `_` (blank) at the start position - Then loop over all `{y, x}` positions. If I find a `#` position, connect that position to an already existing `_` (blank) position and  start carving until it can't go further. Then next iteration (or end of the loop). That way, it can't fail.

Comment: Maybe this is a dumb question, but wouldnt you then just get a whole empty square with "#" walls? Because of the it loops over all positions at sets them to _ (blank). By the way I followed your instructions and the variables now work accordingly! :D

Comment: @Jojo The loop would only examine the positions where blanks are possible, that is +2 every interation. Great that it now works better!

Comment: Yes but if you look at the 4th line (Grid[yPos][xPos]). if you go to every yPos and xPos it will set them all to _ right?

Comment: @Jojo Yes, but only go through those where a blank is possible. That is, only every other position.

Comment: So basically just put everything in a for loop(except the pseudo random generator) that increments 1 till its equal to Height * Width?

Comment: @Jojo +2 in every iteration to skip those where a blank is not possible. I can make an example of what I have in mind if you want. I wont have time until tomorrow though.

Comment: @Jojo I promised I'd come back with an example of what I had in mind - but I sort of liked your idea better the more I thought about it. I still wouldn't do it recursively though so I made [an example](https://godbolt.org/z/7co8YxK6z) where I use a stack object for the possible carving places instead. I made it from scratch so you won't find your `Path` class in there, but a few other helpers. One TODO: Replace the `uniform_int_distribution` with a distribution that will be exactly the same in all implementations so that the same seed will generate the same map on different platforms.

Comment: Wow you really put time into it how nice! I dont want to sound like a brat, but the only problem I have with your problem is that it mostly uses thing far out of my skill range :D. (Only if you have time) could you maybe explain it/simplify it. So I can maybe take a learning experience out of it or something like that?

Comment: @Jojo :-) If there anything in particular in it that you can't figure out I could try to add comments in it to explain it. I added an option so you can see the two different algorithms at work [here](https://godbolt.org/z/5bvb6v89s) It won't work in the online compiler since it'll time out. It draws the map at 10 Hz so you see what it's doing.

Comment: Don't take this personal, but ill first see if I can use my own code, it just feels better if I semi made this code by myself (instead of cntrl c, cntrl v'ing perfect code ;)). Is there any way so that my carvePath function can be improved so that it works each time?

Comment: @Jojo Of course! I wasn't suggesting that you replace it with my code - I just made it to demonstrate an alternative to recursion because the recursion depth can get pretty deep when you create big maps and you then risk running out of stack space. I also updated my answer with a `carvePath` for your program that never fails.

Comment: So what does this : for(auto [toY, toX] : Directions) do?
And I was just wondering can the array be replaced by a vector, because I keep hearing everywhere that array are just the unsafe version of vector?

Comment: It's a [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding). The range-based for loop goes through all the `pair<int, int>` in `Directions` and returns them one by one. By using a structured binding we extract `first` and `second` from each `pair` directly. Sure, you can make it a `vector` instead but the array is more lightweight and fits perfectly here. It's not unsafe. `std::array` a wrapper around a plain C style array of fixed size, which is exactly what's needed. `Directions` always contains exactly 4 `pair<int, int>`.

Comment: Sorry if I may sound annoying, but I want to really understand it. So the auto it turns into an std::pair <int, int> right? SO instead of auto you can use std::pair <int, int>?

Comment: I also keep getting this weird error when I use your code, it says that 'auto' cannot appear in top-level array

Comment: @Jojo No problem :) `auto` is used to deduce what type the variables should be. You can have mixed types in a structured binding, but even if you have only `int`, structured bindings requires `auto`. [usage example](https://godbolt.org/z/res4b99K8)

Comment: @Jojo About that error: Are you compiling with C++17 or later enabled? What compiler are you using?

Comment: I actually don't know how to check, but if it doesn't work is there an alternative then?

Comment: How do you compile your program? What environment/IDE are you using?

Comment: Ah I have MinGW and use G++

Comment: `g++ -std=c++17` should do the trick.

Comment: So 1) I dont actually know where to do that xD, and 2) I am actually not to keen on changing versions. Now that I have finally learned where everything is

Comment: @Jojo Ok, I'll update the answer with something that works with older C++ versions

Comment: You are the best!

Comment: @Jojo :-) Added alternative to the bottom.

Comment: I do get a segment fault ;'(

Comment: Did you change all `{x, y}` accesses to `{y, x}` everywhere in the program? Mixing those tend to mess things up. Note that my `carvePath` version uses `y, x`.

Comment: Ill edit my orig program to what I have now :)

Comment: Don't update the code in the question if that's what you're thinking

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I thought that it would be an easy fix, because that carvePath function on its own was already too long for a comment

Comment: anyway I am going to bed and ill fool around with it tomorrow. If I cant find it by tomorrow evening, can I ping you again?

Comment: @Jojo I rolled that change in the question back. It'll confuse people coming to read the question and answer later if the question suddenly is totally different :-) I'll send you my copy of your original code with the suggested changes. You'll have it when you wake up :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! You will hear from me! :D

Comment: @Jojo You're welcome! [Here's your code with some of my suggested changes to make it work](https://godbolt.org/z/cKc38hhEa)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240808/discussion-between-ted-lyngmo-and-jojo).